# how to restore std::cin to keyboard after using pipe?

Tags: c++, c++11

Problematic code:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "Read from file:" << endl;

    while (!cin.eof())
    {
        array<char, 16> l_array;
        cin.read(l_array.data(), l_array.size());
        cout.write(l_array.data(), cin.gcount());
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Read from keyboard:" << endl;

    cin.rdbuf(cout.rdbuf());

    while (!cin.eof())
    {
        array<char, 64> l_array;
        memset(l_array.data(), 0, l_array.size());
        cin.read(l_array.data(), l_array.size());

        cout << "===== DATA =====" << endl;
        cout << l_array.data() << endl;
        cout << "================" << endl;
    }
}
```

This is how i run my program:

```
./application < file.txt
```

I can read data from pipe without problems but when i want to read it again it is still asociated with pipe. I have no idea how to switch it back. I have found 'rdbuf' function which can change it, but I have no idea how to use it.

I only found examples when you stard with keyboard switch to file and back to keyboard.

Like here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/

But i don't have streambuf remembered so I can't do it like they did. I want to write program which can read most of data from file, and ask only when something is missing or just to ask user in runtime about permision or something. All inside console under linux.

@EDIT
Thank you for help, I post solution

```
class RedirectCinToConsole
{
    protected:
        std::ifstream m_console;
        std::streambuf *m_oldCin;
        bool m_success;

    public:
        RedirectCinToConsole() :
            m_oldCin(0),
            m_success(false)
        {
            m_console.open("/dev/tty");

            if (m_console.is_open())
            {
                m_success = true;
                m_oldCin = std::cin.rdbuf(m_console.rdbuf());
            }
        }
        virtual ~RedirectCinToConsole()
        {
            if (m_oldCin)
            {
                std::cin.rdbuf(m_oldCin);
            }
            m_console.close();
        }

        operator bool () const { return m_success; }
};

int main()
{
    RedirectCinToConsole l_redirect;
    if (l_redirect)
    {
        std::string l_helloWorld;
        std::cin >> l_helloWorld;
        std::cin.ignore();

        std::cout << l_helloWorld;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, you're reading from a file, not from a pipe.  And second, you'll have to use some system dependent means to find the terminal you're running in (**if** you're running in a terminal).  The information isn't available in standard C++.  And finally: `while ( !cin.eof() )` is wrong, wrong, wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening `/dev/tty`.  This will be your process's associated console, if there is any.  If your process was started from a daemon, it could fail.

Comment: That is, of course, purely Unix.  I don't know how you'd do it under Windows.  (MS-DOS had a reserved name for the console.  Something like "CONS", I think.  I don't know if it is still valid under Windows, however.)

Comment: On Windows, `CreateFile("CONIN$", ...)`.  But this question says Linux.

Comment: I missed that.  But it's worth knowing the equivalent under Windows as well.  Presumably `std::filebuf f; f.open( "CONIN$", std::ios_base::in );` would do the trick as well.  Then `std::streambuf* save = std::cout.rdbuf(); std::cout.rdbuf( &theNewFileBuf );` and restoring the saved streambuf when he's done.  (Exactly what you'd do with `/dev/tty` under Unix.

Comment: @James: Assuming that the particular library vendor's implementation of `filebuf::open` passes the correct flags when opening the file (I believe that `OPEN_EXISTING` is required for consoles), then yes.  Otherwise you can use `CreateFile` with the right options and then jump through some hoops to associate a `std::filebuf` with an OS file handle.

Comment: Also, I believe the MS-DOS name was `CON:`.  Typically used in `copy con somefile` (type some stuff, press CTRL-Z) to create a file from keyboard input.

Comment: Good point with regards to the flags.  Although in his case, he was reading; an open for read shouldn't fail just because the file exists.

Comment: Technically possible and all that. But not the correct solution for this user. KISS.

Comment: Thank you! I opened /dev/tty and put his rdbuf into std::cin and it started to read keyboard

Answer (score 6):

It occurs to me that, regardless of the proposed solutions, the easiest
solution (and probably the best) would be to do things the opposite:
don't redirect the input, but pass the filename to the program, and let
it open an `std::ifstream` to read it, keeping `std::cin` free for
interactive input.

Ben Voigt has suggested the standard Unix solution, but on thinking
about it, it seems the above is more natural; it is certainly easier and
more portable.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should use `fstream` to create your own stream and either ask for a file name or take the file name as a command-line parameter. This will leave `cin` available for other input operations.