# getline c++ problems with pipe overflow (?)

Tags: c++, overflow, pipe, getline

I have made a simple program in c++ to read out a file

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    getline(cin, text);
    int textlength = 0;
    textlength = text.length(); 
    cout << text << endl;
    cout << text[3] << endl;
    cout << textlength << endl;
    int number=0;
    cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> number;
}
```

So I compile this program in Win 8.1 pro + mingw and everything is okay. Next I start it by writing in cmd `a.exe < sample.txt`. The compiled program and the txt must be in the same folder.

sample.txt is a file with that text (some random letters, numbers etc.):

```
iuhuefusifsduifhsdiufhfdliuhfdslhfdiufhfdslihfsdui 6 rer4 r4 r4t 4t46 t 4t43t 00 00 002 " & %
```

Everything works fine until the point with the last cin. I cannot enter a number at that point because the entering process is skipped. I also tried to read out the text without the getline function. Instead I simply repeated a cin process and saved the progress one by one in a char. Worked fine until the cin command at the very end. It skipped that yet again.

And ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to restore std::cin to keyboard after using pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164448/how-to-restore-stdcin-to-keyboard-after-using-pipe)

Comment: Forget passing file by `<` if you need to use `cin` afterward. Try to pass the file name by argument list and open it by `ifstream`.

Answer (score 0):

At that point, cin is still reading from your file sample.txt - and failing to read a number, because the getline has already read all the contents of the file.
Adding a second line to sample.txt would let you read a number (but beware that the error handling can get quite tricky if the input is not a number).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet despite adding a new line, it still skips the cin command.

Comment: No, it doesn't skip the command: it tries to read an int and fails - you can check that the cin.good() and cin.fail() status indicators are "unhappy".